# selecting distinct records from a mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table `log` in that I have a column `Message` which is storing log information. Message will contain some event IDs and description of logs
so I want to read all the distinct messages with different event ID's.

What I tried

```
 select distinct message from log limit 100;
```

I am getting all the distinct messages but with the same event ID's

Next

```
select * from log where 
message not like "%1177%" and 
message not like "%609%" and 
message not like "%82%" and 
message not like "%1107%" and
message not like "%23%"
order by ID DESC limit 10;
```

here after getting the log I have to again add a line for getting next unique event id like if I got 23 and want to get other that 23 I have to add `message not like "%23%"` to get the messages other than 23 and this query will size is getting larger.

> So How to write a query which will select different messages with different event ID's?

**edit**

```
Field              | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra                |
+--------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID                 | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| FromHost           | varchar(60)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                  |
| Message            | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |


**edit**
```

sample messages

```
1177|Malformed DNS Packet|12-2-15
1177|Malformed DNS Packet|11-2-15
1177|Malformed DNS Packet|11-1-15
609|IDP Prevention Alert|12-2-15
```

609|IDP Prevention Alert|11-1-15

output

```
1177|Malformed DNS Packet|12-2-15
609|IDP Prevention Alert|11-1-15
```

Comment: What is your actual table schema?

Comment: @Dai, I have Added Description of my table please have a look.

Comment: I don't understand your description. Can you show some  `message` values plus the expected result & why this is the result?

Answer (score 1):

```
 select * from log where group by message,eventID
```

This query will return you the logs based on unique messages along with eventIDs

Comment: Event ID is not a different column It will come within message

Comment: If you see my second Query here I am writing it as `message not like "%23%"`

Comment: so 23,1177, 609 are event ids right? how do you define them? is there any standard size which defines the start of the event ids based on index?

Comment: No these ID's will come at start position and these will be the only numbers so if I go with my second query I am getting the correct result but for reading each other unique record i have to write message not like.......

Comment: separate them till you get the num via regex, use a nested query to re-iterate over it..can you just add 2 sample log messges here?

Answer (score 1):

In Standard SQL this will be:

```
SELECT
   SUBSTRING(message FROM 1 FOR POSITION('|' IN message) -1) AS EventID
  ,MAX(message)
FROM tab 
GROUP BY 
   SUBSTRING(message FROM 1 FOR POSITION('|' IN message) -1)
```

If you don't need to show the EventId in your result you might simply remove it.

In MySQL SUBSTRING/POISITION can be replaced by SUBSTRING_INDEX (and you probably don't need the MAX, too):

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(message, '|', 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, message
FROM "yourTable" GROUP BY id
```

That should return the id along with the message distinctly.

Comment: thanks but ID is not the event id which i'm looking this is just a primary key.

Comment: Just change the column name place event_id in place of id.

Comment: event_id isn't a column it will come in the message column as a subpart of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `MIN()` or `MAX()` functions since your up to different `ID` with unique `message`.

```
SELECT MIN(ID),message FROM log GROUP BY message
```

or

```
SELECT MAX(ID),message FROM log GROUP BY message
```

Comment: Thanks but ID is not the event id which i'm looking this is just a primary key.